# Why is $H_1(S^0)=0$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplex

Why is $H_1(S^0)=0$? We have that $S^0=\{a,b\}$ two points right? So we have singular simplices of the form $\Delta_1 \mapsto$ a and $\Delta_1 \mapsto b$ which are non-zero no? So why is the homology 0? These are not in the boundary, no?

Comment: The singular chain complex is kind of a weird thing and its behavior sometimes depends on the dimension you are in. For example: if we are considering singular n simplices where n is odd, then the constant simplex has boundary 0 (as one might expect). However, if n is even then the boundary of the constant simplex is the constant simplex of one dimension lower. One thing you might think about is when can you represent a generator of $H_n(S^n)$ by a single cycle. This kind of weirdness makes how well singular homology behaves (for some spaces) even more surprising to me.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't knew this rule for odd and even singular simplices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f\colon\Delta_1\to a$ is the boundary of $g\colon\Delta_2\to a$.

Comment: Oh, is it because $\partial (\Delta_2 \mapsto a)=\phi-\phi+\phi=\phi$?

Comment: Yes, you can also 'see' from the dimension.